# TileMap not generated; add to stage?

Tags: libgdx

I'm failrly new to LibGDX and I'm running into a problem. 
I'm building a classically styled RPG/Adventure game in which I'm using a TiledMap(-Renderer) to create the map. I've followed different tutorials but can't get it to work. (last one was DPG's: Full working example [link](http://dpk.net/2011/05/01/libgdx-box2d-tiled-maps-full-working-example-part-1/#p2))

What I need, is a column of buttons on the right side of the screen (implemented that through ImageButtons). One of these buttons lead to a settings-kind of screen and another one should lead to the game map. Under a ClickListener of the button I've added DPK's code of

```
    MapHelper map = new MapHelper();

    map.setPackerDirectory("data/packer");

    map.loadMap("data/world/level1/level.tmx");

    map.prepareCamera((int)stage.getWidth(), (int)stage.getHeight());

    map.getCamera().update();

    map.render();
```

The MapHelper class is an exact copy of dpk's, only change above is the setting of the width and height of the camera. Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to invoke `map.render()` in the `ClickListener` callback.  That would mean the map is only rendered when you click, and then not re-rendered (generally everything gets re-rendered on every screen re-fresh).

I think you need to track the `map` in your application class, and in the ClickListener callback you need to set a flag or somehow "enable" the map (perhaps setting it to something other than `null`).  Then in the application's render() method you can check to see if the map should be rendered or not, and render it if so.

Specifically, move the calls to `prepareCamera`, `getCamera` and `render` out of the `ClickListener`.